# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small, when PLSQL called

Tags: php, oracle, plsql

I've started getting the below error since I added `o_ID` to the procedure, everything worked fine until I added in `o_ID`, is it to do with `o_ID` being set as the wrong data type possibly? I've looked through any other related topics on SO but to no avail.

`o_ID` is being initially set like below before `PR_LOAD_XML_FILE`is called:

```
$id = 0;
$stmt->bindParam('o_ID', $id);
```

**From the Logs**

```
2015-12-18T13:02:06+00:00 ERR (3): An exception occurred while executing 'BEGIN PR_LOAD_XML_FILE (
        i_XML => :i_XML,
        i_FILENAME => :i_FILENAME,
        o_ID => :o_ID,
        on_ErrorID => :on_ErrorID
        );
    END;' with params ["<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?><test><TestDetails><TestVersionId>3244<\/TestVersionId><Marks>20<\/Marks><\/TestDetails><\/test>", "test.csv"]:

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

**Procedure Spec**

```
PROCEDURE PR_LOAD_XML_FILE (
    i_XML IN CLOB,
    i_FILENAME IN XML_DOC.FILENAME%TYPE,
    o_ID OUT NUMBER,
    on_ErrorID OUT INTEGER
);
```

**Procedure Body**

```
PROCEDURE PR_LOAD_XML_FILE (
        i_XML IN CLOB,
        i_FILENAME IN XML_DOC.FILENAME%TYPE,
        o_ID OUT NUMBER,
        on_ErrorID OUT INTEGER
    ) IS
        doc_id XML_DOC.id%TYPE;
        xml        XMLTYPE;
    BEGIN
        ...
    END PR_LOAD_XML_FILE;
```

Comment: Just to be sure, does this procedure work if you call it directly from SQL worksheet with same parameters?

Comment: I've encountered this problem before when the variable from the calling code wasn't declared big enough to hold the return value that Oracle wants to give it. Make sure that when you declare $id that you give it an appropriate size.

Comment: It is probably the clob or filename fields. not the ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when you're calling your procedure, you are setting the variable to receive the value of o_ID as string. Here's my package that mocks yours:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_PR_LOAD_XML_FILE
AS
  PROCEDURE PR_LOAD_XML_FILE (
    i_XML IN CLOB,
    i_FILENAME IN varchar2,
    o_ID OUT NUMBER,
    on_ErrorID OUT INTEGER );
END PKG_PR_LOAD_XML_FILE;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_PR_LOAD_XML_FILE
AS
  PROCEDURE PR_LOAD_XML_FILE (
    i_XML IN CLOB,
    i_FILENAME IN varchar2,
    o_ID OUT NUMBER,
    on_ErrorID OUT INTEGER )
  IS

  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line( 'i_XML: '||i_XML );
    dbms_output.put_line( 'i_FILENAME: '||i_FILENAME );
    o_ID := 999999;
    on_ErrorID := 123456789;
  END PR_LOAD_XML_FILE;
END PKG_PR_LOAD_XML_FILE;
/
```

In SQL*Plus I will first define these two bind variables. Notice how bind variable v_o_ID is set to **varchar2(4)**. This is meant to **fail** because the value of o_ID is set to **999999** in the procedure, which is longer than 4 characters (If the value of o_ID was set to 9999, which is 4 characters or less, then the procedure call would have worked fine, but the bug would still be there, and would creep up on you as soon as the value of o_ID would get bigger than 4 characters):

```
SQLPlus> var v_o_ID varchar2(4)
SQLPlus> var v_on_ErrorID number
```

Now I am calling the procedure in SQL*Plus, and it'll **fail**:

```
SQLPlus> exec PKG_PR_LOAD_XML_FILE.PR_LOAD_XML_FILE( '<heres my XML>', 'heresfilename.csv', :v_o_ID, :v_on_ErrorID);
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Now I will set bind variable v_o_ID to **number**, and the procedure call will be **success**. You can see the received values from the procedure if you print the bind variables using `print` command:

```
SQLPlus> var v_o_ID number

SQLPlus> exec PKG_PR_LOAD_XML_FILE.PR_LOAD_XML_FILE( '<heres my XML>', 'heresfilename.csv', :v_o_ID, :v_on_ErrorID);
i_XML: <heres my XML>
i_FILENAME: heresfilename.csv

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
SQLPlus> print v_o_ID
    V_O_ID
----------
    999999

SQLPlus> print v_on_ErrorID
V_ON_ERRORID
------------
   123456789
```

Comment: That's what it was, the variable wasn't set to a large enough value initially to accept the number being returned by the procedure.

Comment: According to http://php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php it would perhaps be better to specify `PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT` and variable size for 3rd and 4th argument of `bindParam`?

Comment: @Timekiller, I'm using an old custom framework so have to keep it inline with existing code but your right, the way to do it properly would be to use PDO params.